# How to get all stacks, Apps and Instance Ids using AWSOpsWorks client using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am new to AWS OpsWork, I have to get all stack, App and Instance ids from an AWS account using the Java AWS SDK.

I tried with AWSOpsWorksClient, but I couldn't find how to get stack ids using that. Also, I have to delopy a project on all the instance on the particular APP.

Could someone help on this?

Comment: So where did you get stuck, the java, aws sdk for java or others? Did you try with any codes and paste here, that people can help to fix for you?

Comment: I found the code to get AWS Layer and App id by using Stack Id.

Comment: so paste the code here first, and point out where you need get help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to get Layer and App id of AWS account using Stack id.

```
AWSOpsWorksClient opsClient = new AWSOpsWorksClient(awsCredentials);

//To get Layer Id
DescribeLayersRequest layerRequest = new DescribeLayersRequest();
layerRequest.setStackId(stackId);

//This will return the Layers, and then we can get id from the Layer.
DescribeLayersResult layerResult =     opsClient.describeLayers(layerRequest);

//To get App Id
DescribeAppsRequest appsRequest = new DescribeAppsRequest();
appsRequest.setStackId(stackId);

//This will return the Apps from that we can get App id.
DescribeAppsResult appsResult = opsClient.describeApps(appsRequest);

//To get Instance ids
DescribeInstancesRequest instanceRequest = new   DescribeInstancesRequest();
instanceRequest.setStackId(stackId);
instanceRequest.setLayerId(layer.getLayerId());

//This will return the List of Instance, from that we can get the instance id.          
DescribeInstancesResult instanceResult =     opsClient.describeInstances(instanceRequest);
```